# Android Studio emulator freezing computer

Tags: android, android-studio

Just been trying to update my hardware and everything works apart from Android Studio emulator. After loading the emulator it work great for between 1 hour and around two days then the screens freeze and I have to reboot. Have installed a Gigabyte Z170 HD3, 8GB ram and i5 and Windows 10. 500w power supply. Have tried a separate video card but still freezes. Has the latest BIOS updates. I am using three screens and was doing so previous to updating. Shop I purchased from has tried replacing all the (same version) parts but still freezes. They have run all their tests without the emulator running and all good. I have search everywhere I can think of and can't find anyone else having this problem. I'm sure I am not the only person using the emulator! Gigabyte support is useless. All worked before upgrading apart from being a bit slow and was using ARM emulator. Also tried an Asus Z170-K. Crashed after running for two hours. Any ideas of what the problem could be or what to try?

Comment: use genymotion for simulator